# VBS Shutdown Script with Confimation

Tags: vbscript

Looking for a VBscript that creates a desktop shortcut to shutdown the computer.  When actioned by the user; the user will be prompted "Are you sure you want to Shutdown? Yes/No).  When clicking Yes the computer will shutdown while no will exit the script.  I can create the desktop shortcut but am unsure of how to embed the question so it will be executed on action by the user.  Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Could you plsease share any options that you thought it would work but it didn't? Also, as you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question can be answered with a simple search: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vbscript%20shutdown

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyScriptPath 
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"Shutdown the computer")
Call AskQuestion()
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,Name)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If Name = "" Then
        Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-28"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,Msg,Title
    Title = "Shutdown the computer"
    Msg = "Are you sure to shutdown the computer now ?"& Vbcr &_
    "If yes, then click [YES] button "& Vbcr &_
    "If not, then click [NO] button"
    Question = MsgBox (Msg,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Run_Shutdown(30)
    else
        WScript.Quit()
    End if
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Run_Shutdown(N)
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Save your work because your PC will shut down in "& N &" seconds")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

`If MsgBox("Prompt",vbQuestion+vbYesNo,"Title") = vbNo Then WScript.Quit`